# Search on ngram tokenizer and minimum score pass and result should get accordingly

Tags: elasticsearch

I required search ***elastic*** lets consider trigram tokenizer, then *ela, las, ast, sti, tic* are words should search and minimum score is ***60%*** is given  means at least 3-words should match in result like ***elast***.

Comment: You will have to do your own analyzer for your index and set up https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Comment: Thank u for response, I tried https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html, I observed minimum_should_match is not working fine because for ,1%,10%,80% I got same result.please suggest solution for my above requirement

Comment: If you have already tried solutions, you should update your question to give better context and what you have tried and how they have failed.

Comment: searching for "johny" where "Bi-gram analyzer " applied and then bigram terms will "jo","oh","hn","ny",at least 2(50%) pairs should match in data and result I want is only last two documents where first names are john watt and john son but I got "joe" named document also along with them which is not required